# Execute Nexus 3 embedded groovy

Tags: groovy, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I want use Nexus 3's embedded groovy instead of installing groovy package that installs openjdk java.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I want to run this command using the embedded groovy:

```
groovy addUpdateScript.groovy -u "admin" -p "admin123" -n "raw" -f "rawRepositories.groovy" -h "http://localhost:8081"
```

This is to add groovy script support to Nexus3 Chef cookbook:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nexus3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groovy that is embedded in the Nexus Repository Manager is purely available on the classpath of the application. It will be easier to either install a client side groovy system or just upload the groovy script with a shell script that uses simple bash commands. Examples for that are also part of the script examples. You can find them in the examples repository at https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x/scripting/simple-shell-example

I also put together a blog post and video demos of all this at http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/06/08/integrating-nexus-repository-3/

I hope that helps.

Comment: So you are saying I could upload a complex groovy script via curl PUT switching content-type to text/plain like this? 
    curl -v -X PUT -u admin:admin123 --header "Content-Type: text/plain" "http://localhost:8081/service/siesta/rest/v1/script/$name" -d @$myComplexGroovyFile

Comment: Yes. There are example shell scripts for creating, deleting and running jobs in the repo. And a few more and check the video demo to see them in action.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  I already seen the videos, but didn't realize I could upload a groovy file as well. I thought it had to be a json file only.  I did reference videos as well as the scripts: https://github.com/dhoer/chef-nexus3/tree/master/api_examples#api_examples.  Thanks for putting those presentations and examples out there.  I hope add more examples like ldap config etc... to the chef resource.

Comment: That didn't work.  I received a "415 Unsupported Media Type" error when text/plain content type.  The goal is to not require installing groovy package, since that installs OpenJDK.

Comment: You have to make json files that contain the groovy scripts and upload them just like in the videos. It works fine when you do that.

Comment: Could you resolve the problem?
I'm facing the same issue and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

In Nexus 3.10, you have a Groovy 2.4.11 for free, in `$NEXUS_HOME/nexus-3.10.0-04/system/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.11`

You can write a test script:

```groovy
println "hello world"
```

and execute it with

```sh
java -jar groovy-all-2.4.11.jar printme.groovy
```

Of course you still need a JDK/JRE ...

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`I found the solution!
you have to first convert that groovy script to a JSON file and pass that JSON file to your curl or API(for creating script) that you are working with and we can do it with this python file:

```
import json

with open("[THE GROOVY FILE]", "r") as inputfile:
    filedata = inputfile.read()
    jsondata = {}
    jsondata['name'] = 'testscript2'
    jsondata['type'] = 'groovy'
    jsondata['content'] = filedata

    with open("[OUTPUT FILE]", "w") as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(json.dumps(jsondata))
```

the output file is something like this:

```
{
"name": "name",
"type": "groovy",
"content": "..."
}
```

then use this output file which is a JSON file and pass this to that command and there you go!
the command for creat script with REST API is:

```
curl -v -X POST -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type: application/json" "http://<url>/service/rest/v1/script" -d @{output}.json
```

the above command will create a script and you can execute it with:

```
curl -v -X POST -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type: application/json" "http://<url>/service/rest/v1/script/{name}/run
```